# Line break not working when writing to text file in PHP

Tags: php, fopen, text-files, fwrite

I have the following test script:

```
<?php

$myFile = "testFile.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = "Floppy Jalopy\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
$stringData = "Pointy Pinto\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);

?>
```

when run however and opened usign Notepad, the data is returned in a single line without breaks as:

> Floppy Jalopy(crazy box)Pointy
>   Pinto(crazy box)

where i cant find the appropriate character for 'crazy box' but its a REALLY crazy box. WHAT GIVES!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you want to open the file in Windows notepad, you must use Windows line breaks: `\r\n`

Comment: if you open it in Wordpad, it'll cope with either `\n` or `\r\n`, as will a lot of other editors, but Notepad is fussy.

Answer (score 69):

It is best to use `PHP_EOL`. This is cross-platform, so it automatically chooses the correct newline character(s) for the platform PHP is currently running on.

```
$stringData = "Floppy Jalopy" . PHP_EOL;
```

[PHP Constants](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php)

Comment: It's only "best" to use `PHP_EOL` if the files are always to be used on the same platform that your script runs on. In my experience most of the time you create files to be downloaded, e-mailed or parsed later - all cases in which you need files with a *specific* newline character and not the one of the platform the script happens to run on.

Comment: This seems to be best answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your code runs fine.

Use [Notepad2](http://www.flos-freeware.ch/notepad2.html) or [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) if you're working on Windows. The built-in Notepad is unable to cope with Unix-style line endings.

Answer (score 0):

. PHP_EOL; will work universally

Comment: This seems to be repeating [this existing answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4196123).

Comment: this doesn't work in my case. The accepted answer works. +1 vote