# When writing to file, not moving to new line PHP

Tags: php, html

I have 2 files called sellcar.php and interest.php. Users can submit their car details for sale in sellcar.php, and it will get written to a txt file. If buyers are interested, they can submit their details in interest.php, and it will get sent to another txt file. For sellcar.php, everytime there is a new entry, it goes to a new line, but for interest.php, it does not. The code is very similar, so I'm not sure what's happening.

**sellcar.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $fname =$_POST['fname'];
    $lname=$_POST['lname'];
    $phone=$_POST['phone'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $platenum=$_POST['platenum'];
    $model=$_POST['model'];
    $caryear=$_POST['caryear'];
    $desc=$_POST['desc'];
    $travel=$_POST['travel'];
    $owner=$_POST['owner'];
    $repair=$_POST['repair'];
    $file = fopen("CarDirectory.txt","a+");
    fwrite($file,$fname . ',');
    fwrite($file,$lname . ',');
    fwrite($file,$phone . ',');
    fwrite($file,$email . ',');
    fwrite($file,$platenum . ',');
    fwrite($file,$model . ',');
    fwrite($file,$caryear . ',');
    fwrite($file, $desc . ',');
    fwrite($file,$travel . ',');
    fwrite($file,$owner . ',');
    fwrite($file,$repair . "\n");
    print_r(error_get_last());
    fclose($file);
    header("Location:mainmenu.php");
}
?>
```

**interest.php**

```
    <?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $fname =$_POST['fname'];
    $lname=$_POST['lname'];
    $phone=$_POST['phone'];
    $platenum=$_POST['platenum'];
    $price=$_POST['price'];
    $file = fopen("BuyerInterest.txt","a+");
    fwrite($file,$fname . ',');
    fwrite($file,$lname . ',');
    fwrite($file,$phone . ',');
    fwrite($file,$platenum . ',');
    fwrite($file,$price . "\n");
    print_r(error_get_last());
    fclose($file);
}
?>
```

Comment: I think it will depend on the encoding of the files themselves. Can you use `\r\n` for a newline and report the results?

Comment: @esqew so do I do `fwrite($file,$price . "\r\n");`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `PHP_EOL` isntead of `"\n"`.

Example: `fwrite($file,$price . PHP_EOL);`

The purpose of `PHP_EOL` is to automatically choose the correct new line character for the platform you are using.

Comment: Yup, that worked. Sorry for a amateur question. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

PHP has defined constants like `DIRECTORY_SEPERATOR` or `PHP_EOL` (End Of Line - cross platform)

http://php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php

My first hit in google

[Line break not working when writing to text file in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195986/line-break-not-working-when-writing-to-text-file-in-php)

This is called Invariance and Covariance. If you Google it, you’ll find tutorials that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.